# Android Skyline error: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache

Tags: android

When I use skyline demo, I use genymotion api19 4.4.4, but suggested the following error:

```
04-06 03:48:00.249: E/BluetoothAdapter(1779): Bluetooth binder is null
04-06 03:48:07.273: E/OpenGLRenderer(1779): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-06 03:48:07.273: E/OpenGLRenderer(1779): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-06 03:48:07.277: E/OpenGLRenderer(1779): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-06 03:48:07.281: E/OpenGLRenderer(1779): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-06 03:48:07.405: A/libc(1779): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1792 (Thread-99)
```

But I set the Bluetooth permissions, increase the virtual machine memory, but also clean up the simulator cache.Why is there such a mistake?